# Custom react hook throwing error "React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by ProvidePlaidLink."

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, plaid

I'm trying to make a custom react hook for the plaid api's Link feature. My code for the custom hook looks like this:

```
function useProvidePlaidLink() {
    const auth = useAuth();
    // @ts-ignore
    if (!auth.user) return null;
    const [linkToken, setLinkToken] = useState(null);

    const fetchToken = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            const config = {
                method: "post",
                headers: {
                    'earmark-api-key': process.env.EARMARK_API_KEY,
                },
                params: {
                    // @ts-ignore
                    user_id: auth.user.uid
                },
                url:'/api/createLinkToken',
            }
            const response = await axios(config);
            setLinkToken(response.data.linkToken);
        } catch (error) {
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchToken();
    }, [fetchToken]);

    const onSuccess = useCallback(async (publicToken, metadata) => {
        const config = {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
                'earmark-api-key': process.env.EARMARK_API_KEY,
            },
            params: {
                // @ts-ignore
                user_id: auth.user.uid,
                publicToken: publicToken,
            },
            url: '/api/exchangeLinkToken',
        };
        try {
            const response = await axios(config);
        } catch (error) {
        }
    }, []);

    const config = {
        token: linkToken,
        onSuccess,
    }
    const { open, exit, ready } = usePlaidLink(config);

    return { open, exit, ready, fetchToken }
}
```

The first 3 lines are calling my custom auth hook to get the users user id. When the page first renders this is undefined, but a split second later it loads in the uid. However for that split second when it's undefined, my plaid link code throws errors. So I added a quick if statement to the plaid link code to check if it's defined, and if not then return nothing and don't execute the code. This then throws the error `React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by ProvidePlaidLink. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks:` I don't think it's that big of a deal because if I just wait for the split second (and no one will be clicking on the link bank button instantly on page load) then I am able to run the function no problem. However I don't like seeing that error so how should I go about fixing this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning, you check if `auth.user` is `null`, and if it is, you return out of the function. This will cause that every hook *after* the null check will not be run, and that will cause the error.

To solve this, you have to run the hooks even if user is null.

This code should solve the problem:

```ts
function useProvidePlaidLink() {
    const auth = useAuth();

    const [linkToken, setLinkToken] = useState(null);

    const fetchToken = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            // @ts-ignore
            if (!auth.user) return;
            const config = {
                method: "post",
                headers: {
                    'earmark-api-key': process.env.EARMARK_API_KEY,
                },
                params: {
                    // @ts-ignore
                    user_id: auth.user.uid
                },
                url:'/api/createLinkToken',
            }
            const response = await axios(config);
            setLinkToken(response.data.linkToken);
        } catch (error) {
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchToken();
    }, [fetchToken]);

    const onSuccess = useCallback(async (publicToken, metadata) => {
        // @ts-ignore
        if (!auth.user) return;
        const config = {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
                'earmark-api-key': process.env.EARMARK_API_KEY,
            },
            params: {
                // @ts-ignore
                user_id: auth.user.uid,
                publicToken: publicToken,
            },
            url: '/api/exchangeLinkToken',
        };
        try {
            const response = await axios(config);
        } catch (error) {
        }
    }, []);

    const config = {
        token: linkToken,
        onSuccess,
    }
    const { open, exit, ready } = usePlaidLink(config);

    return { open, exit, ready, fetchToken }
}
```

Comment: This will still throw an error because when it tries to make an api call ```auth.user.uid``` will be null and the call will fail, resulting with an error. I can't have the functions run if auth.user is null